# EntityManager is close during Spring JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, entitymanager, spring-test

I have a class test with the following configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ContextPersistenceTest.class)
```

And in ContextPersistenceTest I have the configuration for EntityManager:

```
public @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory {
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  bean.setPersistenceUnitName("unit-name");
  ...
}
```

I inject entity manager as:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManager entityManager;
```

In my @Test I have two consecutive calls to:

```
entityManager.createQuery(sql, MyClass.class);
```

Surprisingly, most of the times the test is executed successfully but sometimes `entityManager` is closed for the second call to `createQuery()` and then I get an:

```
PSQLException: The connection has been closed.
```

Comment: It doesn't say the entitymanager is closed, it tells you the connection is closed. Which is quite a different thing. Is your test `@Transactional`?

Comment: It's not transactional. Should it be?

Comment: If you want a correct `EntityManager` it probably should be yes.

Comment: What do you mean by a "correct" `EntityManager`? Is the connection closed automatically if I do not use it in a transaction? I mean, to execute de first query I do not need to "open" a connection, why would it be automatically closed if I do not explicitly do it.

Comment: The `EntityManager` you get is a scoped proxy. It will be injected for the test and without `@Transactional` I suspect it is fit for a single use. With `@Transactional` it will be open for the duration of the whole transaction, the test method.

Comment: As sometimes it did work, now it seems to always work by using `@Transactional`. Thank you.